# Keep within groups rows with same value in columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe such as :

```
Groups Names            Numbers Value 
G1     Canis_lupus1     10.0    NaN
G1     Cattus_cattus4   10.0    NaN 
G1     Homo_sapiens2    3.0     NaN
G1     Danio_rerio      1.0     NaN
G2     Canis_lupus2     10.0    0.3
G2     Cattus_cattus5   10.0    0.3
G3     Elaph_strangus2  2.0     NaN
G3     Elaph_strangus3  2.0     NaN
```

And I would like to only keep within `Groups` the `Names` with same `Numbers` and with **NaN** values.

So I should then get :

```
Groups Names            Numbers Value 
G1     Canis_lupus1     10.0    NaN
G1     Cattus_cattus4   10.0    NaN 
G3     Elaph_strangus2  2.0     NaN
G3     Elaph_strangus3  2.0     NaN
```

Does someone have an idea please?

Here is the dataframe in dict format if it can helps :

```
{'Groups': {0: 'G1', 1: 'G1', 2: 'G1', 3: 'G1', 4: 'G2', 5: 'G2', 6: 'G3', 7: 'G3'}, 'Names': {0: 'Canis_lupus1', 1: 'Cattus_cattus4', 2: 'Homo_sapiens2', 3: 'Danio_rerio1.0', 4: 'Canis_lupus2', 5: 'Cattus_cattus5', 6: 'Elaph_strangus2', 7: 'Elaph_strangus3'}, 'Numbers': {0: 10.0, 1: 10.0, 2: 3.0, 3: nan, 4: 10.0, 5: 10.0, 6: 2.0, 7: 2.0}, 'Value ': {0: nan, 1: 'NaN ', 2: nan, 3: nan, 4: '0.3', 5: '0.3', 6: nan, 7: 'NaN '}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Create boolean mask to identify the duplicated values in the subset `Groups` and `Numbers`
- Create another boolean mask to identify the `NaN` values in `Value` column
- Combine the masks using logical `and` and filter the rows

```
df[df.duplicated(['Groups', 'Numbers'], keep=False) & df['Value'].isna()]
```

---

```
  Groups            Names  Numbers  Value
0     G1     Canis_lupus1     10.0    NaN
1     G1   Cattus_cattus4     10.0    NaN
6     G3  Elaph_strangus2      2.0    NaN
7     G3  Elaph_strangus3      2.0    NaN
```

Comment: btw sir that key is `'Value '` in the given `dict`

Comment: @AnuragDabas I've created the dataframe using `read_clipborad`

Answer (score 1):

```py
import pandas as pd


def qualified(df: pd.DataFrame):
    return df.duplicated(subset=['Numbers'], keep=False) & pd.isna(df.Value)


print(df[qualified(df)])
```

This should works.

https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html